# Eclipse - This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jvm

I have a 64-bit java 8 on my macbook, but I installed an eclipse plugin who need 32-bit java. I tried `java -version -d32` but this error is prompt :
This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM

I tried to download Java 6 for 32-bit, my plugin is pretty old and I think that Java 6 is better for it, but if there's a way to use Java 8 with an old plugin I would like to know. I got jre-6u45-linux-x64.bin on my folder but I don't know what I should do with this .bin and how eclipse could find it.

Comment: Recent versions of Eclipse require Java 8 to run. On macOS Java 8 is 64 bit only.

Comment: Unless you have hard pressing reasons: **forget** about using Java 6. Heck, Java **9** was released this week. In that sense: don't waste your time on outdated software. Use modern day tools instead. And for the record: in case you are just starting with eclipse and java  - consider giving a try to IntelliJ. More than one savvy Mac person told me that IntelliJ works much better on Macs compared to eclipse.

Comment: I will give a try to IntelliJ, but for the outdated software I don't have the choice I have only that and it's for my university

Comment: Does the plugin really have to run in 32 bit Java? Most plugins don't care, generally only plugins that use native code are restricted like this.

Comment: Yes, it's NXJ and I read a lot of topic about it and I have to run eclipse 32-bit with Java 6 32-bit

Comment: @GhostCat He has hard pressing reasons.  He needs some software to run.

Comment: Maybe you want to tell your university to use modern day tooling. Using stone age technology would not be my first choice when talking about education content.

Answer (score 0):

32-bit Java is not available on modern versions of MacOS.

I would suggest you install VirtualBox to be able to install either Windows or a 32-bit Linux, both of which will allow you to run a modern Eclipse in a 32-bit JVM inside the VirtualBox image.

You may also want to ask the developer of the plugin nicely for a 64-bit version.